# PyQt5 receive and display "JPEG stream"

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I'm trying to receive videostream from remote device and display it in PyQt5 app.
The stream is sending with this code:

```
def get_shot():
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    success, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg",
                                   frame)
    return buffer

def get_feed():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.06)
        buffer = get_shot()
        buffer = buffer.tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + buffer + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return Response(get_feed(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

I tried to use QVideoWidget:

```
self.player = QMediaPlayer(flags=QMediaPlayer.StreamPlayback)
self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl("*link_here*")))
self.player.setVideoOutput(self.videoFeed)
```

But it gets only one shot and stops.

I found that I can do it with QWebEngineView:

```
self.videoFeed.load(QUrl("*link_here*"))
```

But I'm not sure that adding whole web engine to the app just for video-stream is a good idea. Is there any more optimized way to load such stream?